# create a matrix for correlation using 2 separate dataframes

Tags: r

I have two separate dataframes:

```
 **df1**                               **df2**
   A B C D E                         blue yellow green
1                                  1    
2                                  2  
3                                  3
4                                  4
```

I want to merge them by row to create a matrix as below

```
  **matrix**
        A   B   C  D  E
  Blue 

  Yellow

  Green
```

Since the data comes from the sample (rownames from df1 and df2), the columns of the two df can be matched to create a matrix. I am not sure how to do this?

I tried,

```
       merge(df1, df2,
                by="row.names",
                all.x=TRUE)
```

however this doesn't put the column names of the df2 (blue, green red) as the rows in the new matrix. Also, the new dataset doesn't necessarily have to be matrix, if it is a df, I can always convert it to a matrix later on.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please fill out your example with some sample data? Your inputs have rows 1,2,3,4 that just disappear in your expected result, which is pretty confusing. Also not sure what "correlation" has to do with anything - it shows up in your title, but not in your text?

Comment: Or is it a non-traditional correlation matrix, with the correlation between each of the letters and each of the colors? If that's the case, then `cor(df1, df2)` should work.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).